# Extract information from Python file

Tags: python

Say I have a python file

```
def ihavefile(): i = 1
def anotherfile(): pass
```

I want to extract all the functions from the file, like `ihavefile` and `anotherfile`. How do I do that? Do I just read the file line by line and perhaps write a regex or is there a better way?

Comment: does this include methods in classes, what about lambda?

Comment: Or functions within functions?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you mean the source definitions, or the resulting code objects?

Comment: I just want a way to extract general information from a Python file. Functions, identifiers and such. I just want to know what is the usual way of doing this without getting into complexities ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your example:

```
from inspect import getmembers, isfunction, getsource

import your_module
print getmembers(your_module, isfunction)
# [('anotherfile', <function anotherfile at 0x028129B0>), ('ihavefile', <function ihavefile at 0x027F3570>)]
for name, func in getmembers(your_module, isfunction):
    print getsource(func)
```

Comment: Two comments. 1) If the module has global code, that code will run, which might create side effects. 2) If you don't know the module's name in advance, use importlib.